# Ocaml :This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type unit

Tags: ocaml

I got some issue with my code I don't understand. Why did I get this error: `This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type unit`. Here is the code

```
let well_formed (_dimension : int) (_initial1 : _ list)
    (_initial2 : _ list) : bool =
  if List.length _initial1 + List.length _initial2 != 4 * _dimension then false
  else if List.length _initial1 != List.length _initial2 then false
  else
    let c = 0 in
    for i = 1 to _dimension do
      let liste =
        List.filter (fun x -> x == i) _initial1
        @ List.filter (fun x -> x == i) _initial2
      in
      if List.length liste == 4 then c = c + 1 else c = c
    done;
    if c == _dimension then true else false
```

Comment: How do you imagine the `for` loop behaves? it seems like you expect it to return whatever is returned from the expression inside it, but if it did, what would happen to the values returned from previous iterations? Will they just be discarded? If so, why run those iterations at alll?

Comment: Also, you really need to work on your formatting if you expect people to bother to read your code. What you have seems almost completely random. There are tools you can set up to help with that, but you really should be able to write readable code without help. It is an important skill to have when working with other people, which you most likely will need to.

Comment: I changed my code to make it more readable, the first version of my post was the wrong one. But i still have the same issue : This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type unit

Comment: I had to pipe your code through `ocamlformat` to make a slight idea what it is doing. Please, condier using `ocp-indent` or `ocamlformat` to indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

I reformated your code, actually for loop have no impact on your code.

```
let well_formed dimension initial1 initial2 =
    let ll1 = List.length initial1 in
    let ll2 = List.length initial2 in
    let total_list_length = ll1 + ll2 in
    if  total_list_length  != (4 * dimension) then false else
    if ll1 != ll2 then false else
    let c = 0 in


(* this code do nothing : what is expected ?
    for i = 1 to dimension do
      let liste = (List.filter(fun x -> x == i) initial1 )@(List.filter(fun x->x == i) initial2) in
      if ( List.length  liste ) == 4 then c = c+1 else c = c
    done;
 *)


   if c == dimension then true else false
```

You need to learn imperative features of ocaml if you want to write code this way.

For example c = c + 1 return false

if you want to increment a variable you need to create a ref variable.

Comment: Also `if c == dimension then true else false` is an overly verbose way to write `c == dimension`, and while physical equality between ints will work, it's generally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

OCaml is not C/Python/Javascript, in particular

```
x = x + 1
```

means the same as

```
x == x + 1
```

in C or Python, i.e., it is a comparison operator. The `==` operator is the physical comparison (the same as `===` in Javascript).

Also, integers in OCaml are immutable, so if you want to have a mutable number you need to wrap it in a reference and use `:=` for assignment, e.g.,

```
let x = ref 0 in
for i = 0 to 5 do 
  x := !x + 2
done
```